# How does randomBytes or extra entropy effect in wallet generation using ethers?

Tags: ethers.js, randomness, random

I'm trying to generate new wallet using ethers.js
From the examples I got online, `randomBytes(16)` is used. I wonder if I put `randomBytes(128)` make any difference.

Does it make the wallet generation less likely to be generated by other person?
If yes, why don't we just put put `randomBytes(1024)` or even `randomBytes(4096)`?

Also, how about the 16 in the arrayify?
arrayify(hexDataSlice(keccak256(concat([ entropy, options.extraEntropy ])), 0, 16));

```js
const { randomBytes } = require("@ethersproject/random");

let entropy = randomBytes(16);
if (options.extraEntropy) {
  entropy = arrayify(
    hexDataSlice(
      keccak256(
        concat([ entropy, options.extraEntropy ])
      ),
      0,
      16
    )
  );
}

const mnemonic = entropyToMnemonic(entropy, options.locale);
```

Answer (score 2):

The possible entropy lengths are defined in [BIP-39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki).

| Entropy | Mnemonic |
| --- | --- |
| 128 | 12 |
| 160 | 15 |
| 192 | 18 |
| 224 | 21 |
| 256 | 24 |

First `entropy` and `options.extraEntropy` are feed into `keccak256` which returns 32 bytes = 256 bits regardless of the inputs.

Then `hexDataSlice` truncates the output to 16 bytes = 128 bits.

Using more initial data for `entropy` won't make the mnemonic more secure.